# NodeJS Express custom validator how to require in separate file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an application in NodeJS and express.

I am using the express-validator module. I want to create my own custom validation functions.

I am able to get the custom validation working with the syntax below.

```
app.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: {
    isArray: function(value) {
        return Array.isArray(value);
    },
    gte: function(param, num) {
        return param >= num;
    }
 }
}));
```

**Question:** How do I separate the validation functions out into a separate file that I can include in my app.js file?

I would like to "require" the customValidators object literal in the app.js file as a variable. I imagine that my customValidators object is going to be very large and I want to keep the app.js file simple.

I tried the following but it does not work:

**app.js**

```
var customValidators = require('./api/controllers/custom_validators');

app.use(expressValidator(customValidators.customValidation));
```

**./api/controllers/custom_validators.js**

```
var customValidation = customValidators: {
    isArray: function(value) {
        return Array.isArray(value);
    },
    gte: function(param, num) {
        return param >= num;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are exporting customValidation in your custom_validators.js file properly? do

`module.exports.customValidation = customValidation`
because if you are exporting it like 
`module.exports = customValidation`

then `app.use(expressValidator(customValidators.customValidation));` will need to be adjusted to `app.use(expressValidator(customValidators))`

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is just creating a `router`, which you won't need to use `expressValidator` is `app.js`, keeping your code even mode organized:

```
// validators.js
var router = require('express').Router();
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');

router.use(expressValidator({
 customValidators: {
    isArray: function(value) {
        return Array.isArray(value);
    },
    gte: function(param, num) {
        return param >= num;
    }
 }
}))

module.exports = router;
```

And in your `app.js`:

```
app.use(require('./validators'));
```